# PHP menu works in standalone but not when included

Tags: php, html, css

I am developing a website and including two menus into a Home page. The Home page, and both menus have the extension .php. I am testing locally on Apache Server.

**The issue**: One of my menus, which is a top navigation bar, displays correctly on my local server but its menu items / links are not clickable and do not show the rollover effect. This is ONLY when I load the Home page with the menu included via PHP.
When I load the menu page itself (still on my local server), the issue is not present, my menu displays and works fine, including the links.

Please see the code below:

**Home Page**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >

<title>Home</title>

<!-- various css imports, removed for readability -->

</head>

 <body id="home">

 <?php include('top-bar.php'); ?>

 <!-- Container div -->
 <div id="container">

<?php include('menu.php'); ?>

<!-- Container div -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Menu bar**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<!-- various css imports, removed for readability -->

<title>Topbar</title>
</head>


<body id="home">

<div id="headerbar">

      <!-- Centered container -->
      <div id="container">

      <!-- Top bar -->
      <div id="header">


        <div id="maintitle">
            <span style="color: #499DF5">My</span><span style="color: #FFFFFF"> Name</span>     </div>

         <!-- Second menu bar -->
        <div id="menutop">
            <ul>
               <li id="contactme" title="Write me an email"><a href='#'><span>Contact me</span></a></li>

               <li class="last" id="vcf"><a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('contact-card-popup.html','MyWindow','width=300,heig‌​ht=150'); return false;" title="Download my contact card (.vcf or .csv)">Download
  contact card</a></li>

               <li class="last" style="float: right;" id="googleplus"><a target="_blank" title="Follow me on Google+" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/114402922247766544960/posts">
        <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i></a></li>


                <li style="float: right;" id="linkedin"><a target="_blank" title="View my LinkedIn profile" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/myprofile">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i></a></li>

                <li style="float: right;" id="visualize.me"> <a target="_blank" href='http://vizualize.me/myprofile?r=myprofile' title='View my infographic resume on Vizualize.me'><span style="font-weight:bold">Visualize.me</span></a></li>   

            </ul>
        </div>  <!-- End Second menu bar -->

        <div id="jobtitle">Jobtitle</div>

         <!-- End header div -->
        </div>

        <!-- End Centered container -->
        </div>

 <!-- End headerbar div -->
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**And CSS:**

```
/* Layout
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
body {

}


#container {
width:1020px;
position:relative;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -100px;
}

#headerbar{
width:100%;
min-width:500px;
height:130px;
position:absolute;
background: #414141;
}

#menutop {
min-width:500px;
width:1020px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:20px;
}

#wrapper {
clear:both;
height:900px;
width:1020px;
position:relative;
margin: 0 0 0 -25px;
}


/* Top menu: header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#header {
font-family:'Open Sans', sans serif;
}

#maintitle {
font-weight:bold;
font-size:34px;
width:250px;
height:40px;
min-height:60px;
position:relative;
margin-left:40px;
margin-top:25px;
}

#jobtitle {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 14px;
width: 230px;
height: 25px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 270px;
margin-top: 9px;
left: 16px;
top: 36px;
}
```

I tried replacing my php include

```
<?php include('top-bar.php'); ?>
```

with the link relative to the root:

```
 <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/my-website/top-bar.php"); ?>
```

This did not change anything.

I also validated against W3C, just in case it would throw any obvious errors, which it did not.

Any ideas on why the PHP menu works in standalone but not when included? Thank you.

**Edit:**

On a good suggestion of Moshe I updated the JSFiddle he created. Since it seems I cannot use several files in there, I put the code of the top menu inside the home page, where the php import is performed. Doing so clearly makes the links in the menu non-working so it sounds like a CSS issue. I however do not see where the issue is.

http://jsfiddle.net/0ows5vym/4/

And this is the menu only, working fine in standalone: http://jsfiddle.net/fdbvwL3t/

Note: Please diregard the icons not displayed at the far right of the menu, they are based on other imports I cannot easily reproduce here. That part works fine locally.

Comment: Its probably just a path issue. Have you tried the relative path?
`include '../aFolder/AnotherFolder/top-bar.php';`

Comment: The CSS that you have included does not seem complete - see http://jsfiddle.net/0ows5vym/.  Please post the complete working example on jsFiddle.  Also post the "View Source" of the not-working example as a separate jsFiddle.

Comment: Jay, I tried both absolute and relative paths, neither works. My path is correct since first of all the menu gets loaded and displayed, and all php files are in the same folder, which makes it very straightforward. Also tried the dirname(FILE) sugestion from below and it does load and display the menu just like ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']...) does, but in neither case the links work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. Playing with the JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0ows5vym/4/ put me on the right track.

I have a "container" element that was called twice, once in my php menu and then again in the main page. I made the mistake of giving that container a unique ID where it should be a class, if I want to be able to call it several times.

Replacing the container "id" with "class" fixes it, cf here. http://jsfiddle.net/0ows5vym/6/

```
<!-- Container div -->
<div class="container">

<?php include('menu.php'); ?>

<!-- Container div -->
</div>
```

Moshe - thank you for letting me know about JsFiddle. I like that tool. Also your suggestion helped me find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would use dirname(**FILE**) to get current directory.

try using

```
include(dirname(__FILE__). "/my-website/top-bar.php")
```

instead of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

**FILE** constant will give you absolute path to current file
and dirname(**FILE**) to get the directory of current included file

Comment: I tried and it gives me the same result than using ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']...), which I think makes sense since all my php files are in the same website root folder. By "the same result", I mean that the menu is correctly loaded and displayed in the Home page but the menu items do not work, they are not clickable and the links have no rollover.

Answer (score 0):

In which file are you trying to load your php file?

if it is in your index.php (probably),
then you need to take in account your path facing the file where you have it

lets suppose that:

you have a absolute path for your index.php like

```
/var/www/html/thisismywebsite/index.php
```

and your file is in

```
/var/www/html/thisismywebsite/project/someinnerfolder/topbar.php
```

the above would not solve it.

Instead, you may opt for a solution like

```
<?php
define('BASEPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . "/");

include(BASEPATH . "project/someinnerfolder/topbar.php");
```

Just remember, the includes must be relative to the entry point of your application, so your include must be relative to where you start your app.

BONUS:

Don't start all your files with the  tag, and so on, since it will give you issues later on. rather, opt to use a master to keep this kind of html

Comment: Thank you - however this was not a path issue, especially since all php files live in the same folder at the root of my website (for now). I know that it was not easy to understand what was actually being displayed or not until I posted the fiddle, which I will remember for next time. Your bonus sounds interesting! I will look into master pages.